# Image file extension Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm programming an app similar to the email. So when I attach a file to my message I would like to show the filename + small image (icon), this icon should be according the filetype, for example pdf if the file is a pdf, Word id the file is a word file ....

Anyone know how can I find these small images ? Or any representative example ?

Advanced thank

Comment: I have added ios and osx and others tags, you can change your target OS.

Comment: I remember reading about default icons in QLPreviewController. Also have a look at DocInteraction sample project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for iOS then you can use [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToYourFile];
UIDocumentInteractionController *diac = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
NSArray *icons = diac.icons;
if ([icons count] > 0) {
    // This is the smallest available icon:
    UIImage *icon = [icons objectAtIndex:0];
} else {
    // No icon found.
    // According to the documentation, this case *should not* occur...
}
```